# Little arithmetic step in a proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> Uniqueness: let $a \in G$. Assume there's $b \in G$ s.t. $b^2 = a$. Then $(b^2)^{ord(a)} = a^{ord(a)} = e$. Then $ord(b) \mid 2ord(a)$. Since $ord(b)$ is odd, then $ord(b) \mid ord(a)$. So, $b^{ord(a)} = e$. Now $b = bb^{ord(a)} = b^{1+ord(a)}  =  (b^2)^{ord(a) +1} = a.$

I don't get how $b^{1+ord(a)}  =  (b^2)^{ord(a) +1}$. I tried replacing $b$ on the lefthand side with $bb^{ord(a)}$, but that doesn't seem to work. The righhand side evaluates to $b^2 = a$. Please, explain how the equality holds.

edit:

> Claim: Let $G$ be a group with an odd number of elements. Prove that for each $a \in G, x^2 =a$ has a unique solution.
>
> Existence: let $a \in G$ with $ord(a) = m$. Then $m \mid ord(G)$. Since $ord(G)$ is odd, $m$ is odd. Let $x = a^{\frac{m + 1}{2}}.$

[Here's the capture from my book](http://s21.postimg.org/6q6b9vimv/fgfg.png)

Comment: "Since $ord(b)$ is odd" ? Why should this be the case ? Let $a=e$ and $b^2=a$ with $ord(b)=2$.

Comment: Can you please state the assumptions?

Comment: I didn't include the exitence part of the proof where we show that $ord(a)$ is odd if $a \in G$.

Comment: This proof is very confusing to read. We don't know anything of the context and it looks like it is used a lot in the proof. Please include the full statement and proof.

Comment: I added the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is wrong, that's why you can't prove it. In fact you are not proving the uniqueness (which is true). 
To prove the uniqueness suppose that we have $b^2=c^2=a$. As you wrote we have $b^{ord (a) } =c^{ord (a) }=e$ and 
$$b=b^{1+ord (a) } =b^{2k} =a^k=c^{2k}=c^{1+ord (a) }=c$$

Comment: In the first box the part after "now" is incorrect. Keep in mind that what you proved for b is equally valid for c.

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful. I've been fighting this all morning :)